# OpenSSL RSA key generation using Win10

Tags: rsa

I need generate four RSA public modulo n with 64, 112, 256 and 512 bits using OpenSSL, but it wont work in Windows 10. Any help?

Using this as reference: https://www.mobilefish.com/services/rsa_key_generation/rsa_key_generation.php

Code being called:

```
openssl genrsa -out rsa_privatekey.pem 1024 openssl rsa -out rsa_keys.txt -text -in rsa_privatekey.pem
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, what's the code you've used? What are the errors you are receiving?

Comment: openssl genrsa -out rsa_privatekey.pem 1024
openssl rsa -out rsa_keys.txt -text -in rsa_privatekey.pem